# Hosting Jetty on a Windows server and connecting it to a domain name

Tags: jsp, dns, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I am a .Net programmer, lately developing a website in Jsp, using Jetty.
I use Eclipse and the [Maven-Jetty plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin) .

I have a virtual private server, which has IIS installed and serving other (.Net) websites.
My domain name (for the Jsp website) redirects to this server.

My question is:
How do I connect the domain name to the website in Jetty?
Jetty listens to port 8080, and IIS to port 80.

I tried configuring a virtual host in a Jetty configuration file (jetty-web.xml)
(followed [this manual](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/jetty-web.xml)), the result is:
when I open a browser inside my server and navigate to mydomainname.com:8080 I get to
the website. But if I do it externally, I get nothing.

1. What do I need to configure in order to get to my website?
2. How do I overcome the 8080 port number? or do I need to redirect my domain name
   to this port?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can go into the Jetty etc folder and edit jetty.xml.  Look for jetty.port and change the value to 80.  This assumes you don't have another server using port 80 on the virtual private server.

BTW there's a site called serverfault.com that might be better for this kind of question.

Comment: OK in that case I can't help.  I haven't done anything like what you're after and I'm more of a coder than a server guy.